# Regression with vanishing errors

Tags: regression

I hope you find this problem interesting.

Consider the following model:

$Y_t = X_t'\beta + \varepsilon_t$ with $\varepsilon_t \overset{\textrm{iid}}{\sim}\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ for $t=1,\ldots,T$. Call this model $(1)$

and the model

$Y_t = X_t'\beta + \varepsilon_t/T^{\alpha}$ with $\varepsilon_t \overset{\textrm{iid}}{\sim}\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ and $\alpha>0$ for $t=1,\ldots,T.$ Call this model $(2).$

Suppose that $\beta$ and $\sigma^2$ are unknown and you want to estimate them in model $(1)$ and model $(2).$ The statistical properties of $\hat{\beta}$ and $\hat{\sigma}$ (OLS type estimates) are different in model $(1)$ and model $(2)?$ Asymptotically model $(2),$ if $T\to \infty$ becomes deterministic if $X_t$ is deterministic and $T\to \infty.$ Do you think that I can choose to use model $(1)$ to study the behaviour of model $(2)$, if I don't know the rate $\alpha?$

Comment: I believe your statements about asymptotic behavior are erroneous, because you assert no control over $\sigma^2.$  Model (2) is equivalent to model (1) because the "$\sigma^2$" in model (2) corresponds to $T^{2\alpha}\sigma^2$ from model (1).

Comment: $T$ is not stochastic, is the sample size. I want that the stochastic part of the model vanishes when the time dimension (or cross-sectional dimension) increases

Comment: @whuber: this model is such that asymptotically the error vanishes with $T\to \infty$. The problem is that when I do the OLS analysis, I have a rate of convergence different from the usual one, if some usual CLT holds.

Comment: I still don't know why this should be a problem. As to which model to "choose" - well choose the right model - Model 1 is less efficient. Model 2 will behave expectedly for a fixed T. CIs and SEs assume $T$ fixed for repeated experiments. For $T+k$, $k>0$ the homoscedastic assumptions would be wrong. We know Model 2 converges nicely being bounded in probability by the homoscedastic model that cruises in at $o(\sqrt{n})$. It would be more interesting to ask what *is* the rate of convergence in Model 2, or allow $\alpha<0$, or what design(s) allow estimating $\alpha$.

Comment: @AdamO: yes. This is indeed another question. I wanted to understand if someone knows if model $(1)$ can be considered a version of model $(2)$ in some sense. Because this would help me with other questions. But yes, another problem I have is how to estimate $\alpha$ in this framework.

Comment: @AdamO : furthermore, if I take OLS estimate I have that $\hat{\beta}= (X'X)^{-1} X'Y = \beta + (X'X)^{-1} X'\varepsilon/T^{\alpha}$. Hence, if I want to understand the asymptotic distribution, the rate of convergence is $T^{1/2+\alpha} (\hat{\beta}-\beta) = (X'X/T)^{-1} X'\varepsilon/\sqrt{T} \overset{d}{\to} Z$ with $Z$ a normal distribution with mean 0 and a certain covariance matrix.

Comment: I think your question should be: a. are the OLS estimates for model 2 biased? You seem to write that they are. They're actually not - can you show why? The second question is what's the standard error of $\hat{\beta}$ for a given $T$. After that, you can apply Slutsky's theorem and understand the asymptotic properties.

Comment: @AdamO They are not, it's enough the proof of unbiasdness of OLS, $T^\alpha$ does not matter. Indeed, $$\hat{\beta}=\beta + (X'X)^{-1}X'\varepsilon/T^{\alpha}.$$ Taking the conditional expectation w.r.t $X$, you can see immediatly that $\mathbb{E}(\hat{\beta}|X)=\beta$. The thing that is strange is that the $\hat{\beta}$ in this framework seems super-consistent, i.e. I need a rate of $\alpha+1/2$ to get the asymptotic distribution. But I want to follow also your suggestion. How would you estimate $\alpha$ in this framework?

Comment: If you want the error to vanish asymptotically, you haven't expressed that with sufficient clarity.  There also is no clear sense in which your model (2) "asymptotically" becomes deterministic, because for every finite sample it is *not* deterministic.  One difficulty is that your model (2) doesn't appear to have any applications: in what statistical setting would any parameter vary with the sample size??

Comment: @whuber : Thank you for your comment. I have an application in asset pricing related to this question. But I don't want to go into the details. I am trying to solve this simple problem and understanding how to define a model that is with vanishing error terms in the limit (its variance becomes zero as T increases). This is what I need in my theoretical setting, if I can obviously.

Comment: I wonder whether this is really a suitable model for your application.  It's really a *sequence* of models.  Looking at the situation this way might help you separate the properties of OLS from the asymptotic properties of your sequence.

Comment: Thank you @whuber. Exactly, I want that a sequence of models converges to a nonstochastic limit asymptotically. The OLS properties are not difficult to find on beta, as I have shown before. But I am trying to understand if I can transfer the properties of $\hat{\beta}$ of model $(1)$ in model $(2)$. So, the sequence of models, can be studied with a linear model, forgetting about $T^\alpha$?

Comment: As I wrote earlier, I would suggest separating the two concepts: consider a 2D sequence indexed, say, by natural numbers $(N,T)$ where $N$ is the sample size and $T$ is your parameter.  For fixed $T,$ OLS theory gives you the asymptotics in $N;$ and for fixed $N,$ you have stipulated the asymptotics in $T.$  To get a definite result, you will need to indicate exactly how $(N,T)$ diverges; it appears you intend $T=N.$  That gives a straightforward approach to analyzing the situation.

Comment: Thank you very much @whuber. This could be a good idea to investigate!